# Maven not including jar files in classpath during packaging

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting started with Maven and have come across a problem I'm unable to resolve. It seems the jar files required for my applicaiton to run are not in the classpath. Should Maven not be taking care of this during mvn package?

When I run mvn package, I get error:

```
[ERROR] /home/dev/Desktop/maventest/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java:[79,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UpnpService
  location: class com.mycompany.app.App
[ERROR] /home/dev/Desktop/maventest/my-app/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java:[79,39] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UpnpServiceImpl
  location: class com.mycompany.app.App
```

The sample code does say: "You need cling-core.jar and its dependencies (seamless-*.jar files) on your classpath to build and run this code. "

But is this not something maven should take care of? If not, how do I include these files?

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>4thline-repo</id>
      <url>http://4thline.org/m2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fourthline.cling</groupId>
      <artifactId>cling-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is sample code I'm trying to run:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import org.fourthline.cling.model.message.header.STAllHeader;
import org.fourthline.cling.model.meta.LocalDevice;
import org.fourthline.cling.model.meta.RemoteDevice;
import org.fourthline.cling.registry.Registry;
import org.fourthline.cling.registry.RegistryListener;

/**
 * Runs a simple UPnP discovery procedure.
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // UPnP discovery is asynchronous, we need a callback
        RegistryListener listener = new RegistryListener() {

            public void remoteDeviceDiscoveryStarted(Registry registry,
                                                     RemoteDevice device) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Discovery started: " + device.getDisplayString()
                );
            }

            public void remoteDeviceDiscoveryFailed(Registry registry,
                                                    RemoteDevice device,
                                                    Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Discovery failed: " + device.getDisplayString() + " => " + ex
                );
            }

            public void remoteDeviceAdded(Registry registry, RemoteDevice device) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Remote device available: " + device.getDisplayString()
                );
            }

            public void remoteDeviceUpdated(Registry registry, RemoteDevice device) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Remote device updated: " + device.getDisplayString()
                );
            }

            public void remoteDeviceRemoved(Registry registry, RemoteDevice device) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Remote device removed: " + device.getDisplayString()
                );
            }

            public void localDeviceAdded(Registry registry, LocalDevice device) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Local device added: " + device.getDisplayString()
                );
            }

            public void localDeviceRemoved(Registry registry, LocalDevice device) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Local device removed: " + device.getDisplayString()
                );
            }

            public void beforeShutdown(Registry registry) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Before shutdown, the registry has devices: "
                        + registry.getDevices().size()
                );
            }

            public void afterShutdown() {
                System.out.println("Shutdown of registry complete!");

            }
        };

        // This will create necessary network resources for UPnP right away
        System.out.println("Starting Cling...");
        UpnpService upnpService = new UpnpServiceImpl(listener);

        // Send a search message to all devices and services, they should respond soon
        upnpService.getControlPoint().search(new STAllHeader());

        // Let's wait 10 seconds for them to respond
        System.out.println("Waiting 10 seconds before shutting down...");
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // Release all resources and advertise BYEBYE to other UPnP devices
        System.out.println("Stopping Cling...");
        upnpService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The example code is from: http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.xhtml#chapter.GettingStarted

Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the example I was using was missing import statements:

```
import org.fourthline.cling.UpnpService;
import org.fourthline.cling.UpnpServiceImpl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven takes care of the dependencies that you declare in pom.xml, in order to resolve your issue you should add the cling-core dependency in pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>4thline-repo</id>
      <url>http://4thline.org/m2</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fourthline.cling</groupId>
      <artifactId>cling-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fourthline.cling/cling-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.fourthline.cling</groupId>
      <artifactId>cling-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Replace your pom.xml with the above and see maven downloads the jars  including all its dependencies.